# Kubernetes env variable not attached via PodDefault

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am working in kubeflow notebook server. I need to add some configurations which are environment variables. So that, I have decided create the configmap and the PodDefault.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  namespace: app
data:
  PLACE: /auth
  USERNAME: root
  PASSWORD: l3tm3in
```

This is my configmap file. I have attached this file in PodDefault object using below syntax

```
apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1alpha1"
kind: PodDefault
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  namespace: app
spec:
 selector:
  matchLabels:
    test-configmap: "true"
 desc: "Test Configmap"
 envFrom:
 - configMapRef:
    name: test-configmap
```

Actually the values are coming kubeflow configuration section. But it's not attached in the notebook(Pod)

Could anyone know about how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have never used kubeflow but based on [the sourcecode](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/admission-webhook/main.go), this should be the solution:

```
apiVersion: "kubeflow.org/v1alpha1"
kind: PodDefault
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  namespace: app
spec:
 selector:
  matchLabels:
    test-configmap: "true"
 desc: "Test Configmap"
 containers:
 - envFrom:
   - configMapRef:
      name: test-configmap
```